# Conditional key in dictionary - python

Tags: python, dictionary, nonetype

I have a function `create_group` with an optional parameter `user_device=None`. If a non-None value is provided for `user_device`, I want a dictionary `targeting_spec` to include the key-value pair `"user_device": user_device`, and if no non-None value is provided, I do not want `targeting_spec` to include this key-value pair.

How I do it now:

```
def create_group(..., user_device=None, ...):
    ...
    targeting_spec = {
        ...
    }
    if user_device:
        targeting_spec["user_device"] = user_device
    ...
```

Is this an accepted way of doing this? If not, what is? I ask because this seems like the type of thing Python would love to solve elegantly.

Comment: This will not set `parameters[user_device]` to `user_device` if `user_device` is something that evaluates to `False` in a boolean context that is not `None`, such as the empty string, `0`, an empty list or tuple, and so on. If you do not want this behaviour, change your check to `if user_device is not None`.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with this way of doing it. Although you could just enter it into `parameters` as `None`. As long as you account for it being `None` down the line it should work fine either way.

Comment: Ooh, good point. Turns out if it were any of those things I still would not want user_device in targeting_spec, so my statement "If a non-None value is provided..." was not technically accurate because things like "" or [] are also not needed by me, (like None). I will edit, and fix my variable names to match description.

Comment: Actually I will go with non-None, and thus change the check to be `if user_device is not None:` but that is a valid concern which I did not take into account before.

Comment: it would be nice if you could do something like `{'key1': value1, 'key2': value2 if value2, 'key3': value3}`

Comment: Is it possible to do this in a way that does require `targetting_spec` to be mutable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your approach is fine, *provided* you don't need to support empty values.

Consider passing in `user_device=0`, for example. `user_device` is not `None`, but it *is* a falsey value.

If you need to support falsey values *apart* from `None`, use `is not None` to test:

```
if user_device is not None:
    parameters["user_device"] = user_device
```